# How to select multiple nodes based on a maximum child element value in XPath 1.0 (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath, xpath-1.0

Environment:

- Writing a WPF application using C# (and Visual Studio 2015)
- Restricted to using XPath 1.0

Goal: I need to select multiple specific xml nodes from an XML document based on the value of a child element within the specific node

Situation so far: Currently, I have several XPath queries that select individual nodes and get the Value of attributes and elements.  The one I am having trouble with is shown below.

```
var xUsageSummary = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("
            /root
            /table[not(contains(@tagname,'pole'))]
            /*[not(maximum_usage < ../*/maximum_usage)]");
```

**Edited to show modified `table` and updated `maximum_usage`**

It seems that the issue is coming from the last section of the XPath string, at the `../*/maximum_usage`. While the elements being selected are filtered by the `not(contains(@tagname,'pole'))` predicate, I think that `../*/maximum_usage` is not getting the correct data based on the filter. Perhaps the `*` should be replaced with something that would represent the name of the element from which the `maximum_usage` value is being taken.

```
<root>
    <table tagname="summary_of_brace_usages">
        <summary_of_brace_usages>
            <brace_label>brace1</brace_label>
            <maximum_usage>55.00</maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseA</load_case>
        </summary_of_brace_usages>
        <summary_of_brace_usages>
            <brace_label>brace2</brace_label>
            <maximum_usage>70.00</maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseA</load_case>
        </summary_of_brace_usages>
    </table>
    <table tagname="summary_of_pole_usages">
        <summary_of_pole_usages>
            <pole_label>pole1</pole_label>
            <maximum_usage>23.63<maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseB<load_case>
        </summary_of_pole_usages>
        <summary_of_pole_usages>
            <pole_label>pole1</pole_label>
            <maximum_usage>85.25<maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseB<load_case>
        </summary_of_pole_usages>
    </table>
    <table tagname="summary_of_x_arm_usages">
        <summary_of_x_arm_usages>
            <brace_label>xarm1</brace_label>
            <maximum_usage>42.00</maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseA</load_case>
        </summary_of_x_arm_usages>
        <summary_of_x_arm_usages>
            <brace_label>xarmA</brace_label>
            <maximum_usage>95.00</maximum_usage>
            <load_case>CaseA</load_case>
        </summary_of_x_arm_usages>
    </table>
</root>
```

**Edited to show modified sample XML**

The desired output from the XML sample above should be an IEnumerable that contains two XElements;

```
/root/table/summary_of_brace_usages //(where @maximum_usage 70, because it is the largest "maximum_usage" value)
```

and

```
/root/table/summary_of_x_arm_usages //(where @maximum_usage is 95, because it is the largest "maximum_usage" value)
```

After the correct IEnumerable is returned, I will be able to get the other element values and write them to variables and ultimately properties of a class so they can be put into a FlowDocument for printing with my WPF application.

Any help is much appreciated and I will be glad to give any additional information if it is needed - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `name()/maximum_usage` isn't valid XPath expression. Replace `name()` with `../*/maximum_usage` to get all `maximum_usage` within within current `table`. Also, `@` is used to reference attribute, so you need to remove that since it is a child element instead of attribute that you're working with in this case :

```
/root
/table
/*[not(maximum_usage < ../*/maximum_usage)]
```

**<kbd>[`xpath demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/j26xCQ8DB)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you for the useful advice. I changed everything to reflect your answer and it is actually returning something now, so that's good. Unfortunately, it seems that I simplified my sample code so much that an important factor was omitted. I will update my original post to show the change.